# How to Change Page Title after Navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have set a Title for a FirstPage Using `App._variable = "Title"`, after `Navigation.PushAsync(new SecoundPage())` i am setting `App._variable = "New Title"` and then `Navigation.PopAsync())` to go back to FirstPage, When I Navigate Back to FirstPage still the Title is "Title", How could i change this?

**EDIT**
App.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class App : Application
        {
        public static int _ItemId { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());
        }
    }
}
```

FirstPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void BtnSecoundPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecoundPage());
}
```

SecoundPage.xaml.cs (Has a ListView)

```
private void LVCustomerList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as Items; //Item Model

    App._ItemId = selectedItem.ID;
    Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: Are you using NavigationPage? Provide some code to make your question clear.

Comment: I provided an answer, then you added code to your question that in no way relates to what you’re asking. I’m so confused.

Comment: @BradDixon Sorry for the Delay in updating the Question, but That's what i was asking. kindly please go through it again.

Comment: @MubahMohamed that’s ok, but does my answer even fit your question?

Comment: Can you add your XAML files so i can show you what to do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup your bindings correctly.

In your XAML, make sure you set a binding for your title ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="PlaypenApp.TestPage"
    Title="{Binding Title}">

</ContentPage>
```

... then in your code-behind (if that's what you're using) you need to ensure you set the binding context for the page ...

```
this.BindingContext = this;
```

... put the above line of code just before the call to InitializeComponent()

Now add a property to your page, this will replace your usage of App._variable ...

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

... then to test it all out, use this code (which has some of the code I have specified above) ...

```
public TestPage()
{
    this.BindingContext = this;

    Title = "Old Title";

    InitializeComponent();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        Title = "New Title";
    });
}
```

After 2 seconds, the title on the page should change.

I hope that works for you.  Let me know how you go.